# Replace characters in mysql query doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, database, replace, character

I have a database containing information about different items (3 colums). The values of the "itemname" column (which is the one that is being searched) contain special characters which makes it hard for users to find what they are looking for.

Format: "Bayonet / Marble Fade (Factory New)"

Right now users have to type the exact structure including the "/" and "(" and ")". I want these characters to be ignored so a "Bayonet Marble" will give the same results as a "Bayonet / Marble".

My (working) query:

```
"SELECT itemname, itemprice, itemupdate FROM pricedata WHERE itemname LIKE '%" . $search . "%' ORDER BY itemprice DESC LIMIT 20");
```

The non-working solution I found to ignore the /.

```
"SELECT itemname, itemprice, itemupdate FROM pricedata WHERE replace(itemname, ' / ', ' ') LIKE '%" . $search . "%' ORDER BY itemprice DESC LIMIT 20");
```

Values shouldn't be changed permanently. Only for the query.

What would be the right way to do it? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Hey Thomas! I see you're looking to improve database searches so they're less sensitive to spelling discrepancies. While I can't answer the question, I can suggest that you simplify the text: if you're more concise, SQL experts are more likely to read and help you with your question. (For example, you can probably strip the first two paragraphs and say something like "I'm trying to build a searchable database of items. The names are complex, so it's hard for the user to find what they're looking for." Much simpler, same amount of context.) Welcome to Stack Overflow: good luck with the project!

Comment: Hello Dylan, thanks for the kind words. I tried to shorten it as much as possible. I hope that someone can help me. :)

Comment: Much clearer! Glad to be of help.

Comment: You are. Have a nice evening!

Comment: Have you considered using a full-text index instead of `LIKE`? Because even if you replace all the special characters, the user still has to get the right number of spaces. And the query will be very slow since it can't use an index.

Comment: Your code works for me: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71c6a1/1

Answer (score 0):

I'd advocate doing the hard work before you get to the query. PHP has excellent features for working with strings. In this case, you could remove any characters you don't want, then split the string at its spaces, and finally construct a query from individual words:

```
$user_query = 'word1 (word2 word3';

//remove any stray characters you don't want
$remove = array('/', '\\', '(', ')');
$cleaned = str_replace($remove, "", $user_query); 

//breaks string at spaces
$words = explode(" ", $cleaned); 
print_r($words);

//finally, build the query
$query = "SELECT itemname, itemprice, itemupdate FROM pricedata WHERE ";

$count = count($words);

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
    if(strlen($words[$i]) > 0){
        $query .= 'itemname LIKE %' . $words[$i] . '% ';
        if($i < ($count - 1)){
            $query .= 'OR '; //could also be AND
        }
    }
}

$query .= "ORDER BY itemprice DESC LIMIT 20";
```

Answer (score 0):

After you have replaced the slash with a space, you are now left with 3 spaces between the 2 words. In a "like" matching, spaces must also match.

Try replacing all white spaces In your search field and search string with empty strings. Or multiple consecutive white spaces with a single space.